# How do i do algorithm to find LCM of two positive integers entered by user using automatic counter loop structure?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I have tried a few algorithm that seems to work. Hope everyone can help to check for me...

> Solution 1:

```
Start
Get num1, num2
Set max_num1 = num1
set lcm = 0
loop:counter = 1 to 100 Step 1
    if max_num1%num2==0
        lcm = max_num1
    else
        max_num1 = max_num1 + num1
    endif
loop-end:counter
print lcm
End
```

> Solution 2:

```
Start
Get num1, num2
set lcm = 0
loop:counter = 1 to 100 Step num1
    if num1%num2==0
        lcm = num1
    else
        num1 = num1 + num1 - counter
    endif
loop-end:counter
print lcm
End
```

Comment: The "too much of this answer is code" warning is there for a reason. Format code as code and improve your question.

Comment: noted, it was my first time asking question(sorry for the disturbing long code.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

1. Start
2. Input num1
3. Input num2
4. Loop: counter i in range 2 to minimum of num1 and num2
5. If num1%i==0; Go to 6, else go to 8
6. If num2%i==0; Go to 7, else go to 8
7. Print i is LCM
8. Print '1 is the only LCM'.
9. Stop

Comment: thanks for helping, but my question must use an automatic counter loop.